# maintain aspect ratio while creating thumbnails in ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

**Description :**

So after a thorough search I went with the answers I found on Stack Overflow about video uploading and thumbnail creation by using ffmpeg .. I am using the following code to create the thumbnail of the video I am uploading .. every thing was working fine until I modified my code to maintain the aspect ratio of the created thumbnails as well .

```
$ffmpeg = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";
                $videoFile = $_FILES['vid']['tmp_name'];
                $videoFilename = "1.jpg";
                $size = "120x90";
                $getseconds = 5;
                $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $videoFile -vf scale='min(300\, iw):-1' -ss $getseconds -s $size -vframes 1 $videoFilename";
```

Now nothing is working ... what am I doing wrong .. anyone??

Comment: You really need to be careful when passing in arguments to external applications.  Make sure you use `escapeshellarg()`.  Also, is your FFmpeg binary really called `ffmpeg`, and not `ffmpeg.exe`?  And, where are you actually executing `$cmd`?

Comment: i am using shell_exec($cmd);

Comment: You should show the actual and complete `ffmpeg` console output. It will tell you what the issue is (if `ffmpeg` is the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is that what you are looking for :**

```
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -itsoffset -1 -i $videoFile -vframes 1 -filter:v scale='400:-1' -ss $getseconds  image.png";
```

le me know if it works :)